# How to render a variable containing `new Image()` in AngularJS ng-repeat?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an array that looks like this:

```
var imageList = [ image1, image2, image3 ];
```

Each element in this array is a variable containing `new Image()`. 
For example: `var image1 = new Image()`.

I preload each image using `.onload` event for each element after setting its url. Only after all the images have been loaded, that anything else can happen.

How do I output each array element in AngularJS and show the image?

```
<li ng-repeat="image in imageList">
   {{ image }}
   /* I want the expected output of the above line to look like
      <img src="./img/xx.svg" /> */
</li>
```

I don't want to do anything like the code below since I already created each element in the array as a new Image():

```
<li ng-repeat="image in someImageList">
   <img ng-src="{{ image.url }}" />
</li>
```

The current output if I do `{{ image }}` is just list of {}. If use just `image`, the output is a list of "image" string.

The reasons why I'm creating new image elements using JavaScript instead of using the `<img/>` tag are that 1. I need to preload the images and 2. I need to draw these images in `<canvas>`. It's redundant to create `<img/>` for the same image sources. Also, it makes opening for a modal that shows a list of these images very slow to open. So if the images are preloaded already, the modal *might* open faster.

Comment: What's wrong with using the sample code? Since the image is cached it wont make another call to the network. I'm interpreting your question as "how do you draw an image onto a canvas from an Image object?" is that correct?

Comment: No. So `new Image()` is the same as the HTML <img />. To make an image, normally it's <img src="xx.jpg" />. But if I do `var _img = new Image(); _img.src = "xx.jpg";` how do I output variable `_img` to be `<img src="xx.jpg" />` ?

Answer (score 2):

You will need to convert the image to a data uri and save that string.

```
$scope.images = [];

loadImage('./img/xx.svg');

function loadImage(src) {
  var img = new Image();

  img.onload = function() {
    // Create a canvas
    var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');

    // Be sure the canvas is the same size as your image
    canvas.width = this.width;
    canvas.height = this.height;

    // Draw the image to the canvas
    canvas.getContext('2d').drawImage(this, 0, 0);

    // Add the data uri to your scope
    $scope.images.push(canvas.toDataURL('image/png'));

    // "Notify" Angular something has changed
    $scope.$apply();
  }

  img.src = src;
}
```

Then you can print it like this-

```
<li ng-repeat="image in images">
   <img ng-src="{{ image }}" />
</li>
```

Image will be the data uri (not a url).

How you implement this with the canvas is up to you.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your answer. I tried this solution. But I'm wondering, doesn't .toDataURL increase the file size to 33%? And when running this code (from create a canvas element to .toDataURL()), it's quite slow. If I add 2 more pictures, it's even slower to finish. Any solutions?

Comment: In what way is it slow? You may want to optimize your loop with `track by` and single bind `ng-src`.